# How to find biography (dates of birth/death, etc) of prominent 18th Century English person?

Tags: birth-records, 18th-century, death-records, heraldry

Hugh Clark is the author of ["An Introduction to Heraldry"](https://archive.org/details/anintroductiont00wormgoog), but I could not find anything about his biography and even his dates of birth and death. How can I learn more about an 18th century author such as this?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/ref:odnb/62418

Comment: I agree with @ColeValleyGirl about Google - I found the Oxford DNB reference on page 4 of the google results for "hugh clark heraldry" which was a fairly obvious search term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [British Library](http://www.bl.uk/) have a number of works by him [listed in their catalogue](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do;jsessionid=688BCABF6B36EFE8B408F1C75CF072B8?vl%28freeText0%29=Hugh%20%20Clark,%20active%201775-1784.&vl%28488279563UI0%29=creator&vl%28488279562UI1%29=all_items&fn=search&tab=local_tab&mode=Basic&vid=BLVU1&scp.scps=scope%3a%28BLCONTENT%29) and record him as active from 1775 to 1784.

There is also an [entry](http://www.oxforddnb.com/index/62/101062418/) in the [Oxford Dictionary of National Biography](http://www.oxforddnb.com/public/index.html) which may relate to him and which gives dates of 1745 to 1822 though you need a subscription (or access to the printed version) to see the whole entry.